# Kotlin Get Value from JSON

Tags: kotlin

In the kotlin repl:

```
>>> import java.io.StringReader
>>> val json = p.parse(StringReader("""{"abc":"123"}""")) as JsonObject
>>> json.string("abc")
error: unresolved reference: string
json.string("abc")
     ^

>>> json
JsonObject(map={abc=123})
```

Get error unresolved reference.  None of the examples here: https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import the [`string` function](https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon/blob/db522180a5ebefa387afdbd5396de436a7f76ba9/src/main/kotlin/com/beust/klaxon/Lookup.kt#L25) as well, since it is an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html), and it [is not imported](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#scope-of-extensions) together with its receiver type `Parser` by default:

```
import com.beust.klaxon.string
json.string("abc")
```

Comment: What would be best practice?  Just importing all of the ones you'd want to use?

Comment: If you need many functions from the same package, you can import the whole package instead: `import com.example.*`. But this can lead to the resolution and completion namespaces pollution, so I 'd not recommend doing that on big packages from which you only need a few functions. Apart from that, it's up to you. AFAIR, IntelliJ default behavior in regular sources (non-script ones) is to replace separate imports with a package one when their number reaches some value like 4.